# Scala 3.2.0 : Illegal start of toplevel definition

Tags: scala

Scala people!

So i'm trying to learn scala, and whenever i use the interpreter, everything is fine. But if i try and code in a script and run it with the scala command, the same thing happens every time.
So this is a concrete problem i'm having, with an example from the book "Programming in Scala".

```
val greetStrings: Array[String] = new Array[String](3)
greetStrings(0) = "Hello "
greetStrings(1) = ", "
greetStrings(2) = "world"

for (i <- 0 to 2)
  print(greetStrings(i))
```

gives me the error:

```
-- [E103] Syntax Error: /Users/USER/scala/pa.scala:2:0 -------------
2 |greetStrings(0) = "Hello "
  |^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |Illegal start of toplevel definition
  |
  | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
-- [E103] Syntax Error: /Users/USER/scala/pa.scala:7:2 -------------
7 |  print(greetStrings(i))
  |  ^^^^^
  |  Illegal start of toplevel definition
  |
  | longer explanation available when compiling with `-explain`
2 errors found
Error: Errors encountered during compilation
```

Actually whatever code i try to run, gives me this exact error.

For reference, i've never coded in java, so im not familiar with any particularities.  I've mostly been coding in f# and python.

Comment: You need to wrap your code in a main class or at least a class or object.

Comment: This should not happen. What Scala version do you have ?

Comment: It says "Scala 3.2.0 (1.8.0_292, Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)"

Comment: I see. Your code is for Scala 2. It will run without issues on Scala 2. On Scala 3 you need to use the [@main](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html) to mark an entry point to your script.

Comment: Please [edit] the information about your scala target version into your post.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054995/how-can-i-run-a-scala-3-scala-script

Comment: The proposed duplicate is cluttered with obscure error messages from 2.11, I like this question here much better. I'd rather prefer to close the other one as duplicate of this one (note that temporal order doesn't matter).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run it with `scala` (`scala3`), then you have to add a `@main` entry point:

```
@main def entryPoint() =
  println("Hello, World")
```

If you insist on having statements on the top-level, use [`scala-cli`](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/scripting/).

Comment: What is the difference between your option and encapsulating it into an object?

Comment: @MemphisMeng If you encapsulate it into an object, then you'll have to work with `Array[String]` directly, whereas the `@main` annotation will result in the generation of a rudimentary command line parser, allowing you to accept a fixed number of arguments of some basic types for which the parsers are provided, something like `@main foo(bar: String, baz: Int, quuz: Float)`. To be honest, at the current stage, the generated command line parser is way too simple, so I use the `@main` simply because it's shorter. See details here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/methods-main-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

It is worthy to mention that with scala-cli, the scripts have to have .sc extension, like this:

`scala-cli game.sc`

See https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/guides/scripts